# How to upload multipart files in aws s3 bucket using javascript sdk in browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried using the function

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'mybucket'}});
var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type};
bucket.createMultipartUpload(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Its getting successful response consists of uploadedid but i cant find the file in the s3 bucket. So is there any other ways for multipart upload files from javascript sdk from browser??. I am using aws cognito for authentication.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is a four step process. You have called the first Api and there are three remaining apis to be called.

The order is as follows :

2.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#uploadPart-property.
3.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listParts-property.
4.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#completeMultipartUpload-property.

For all the above three apis you have to use the same key-name (that you have used in your first api) and upload-id (that you got from the first api's response)

In second api, you have to upload your file along with a 'partnumber' of your choice.

Then from third api call, you can get the 'TagId' generated for your file along with the 'partnumber' you used.

Now using this TagId and partnumber, you have to call the final api.

This completes your file upload.

Answer (score 1):

The key you are using is the filename. So the file if uploaded properly should be present at `mybucket/file.name`.Moreover you can log things on console to see if anything is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you use .upload, it will automatically use post multipart. and you must set your s3 bucket cors policy to allow POST, and HEAD plus exposedHeaders ETag